# Difference between Plus[x_, y_] and Plus[_, _]

Tags: pattern-matching

Why did `MatchQ[a + b + c, Plus[x_, y_]` is considered true?

In my  opinion, it should only consider  2 elements within `Plus`, such as `MatchQ[a + b, Plus[_, _]]` true.

Why is this `MatchQ[a + b, Plus[_, _]]` false?

Where did I get wrong? Please point out.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Adding `HoldPattern` is simply not working. And How can I make `MatchQ[a + b, Plus[_, _]]`  true?

Comment: `MatchQ[a + b, HoldPattern[Plus[_, _]]]` works for me.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  I thought it was like this. `MatchQ[(a + b  + c), Plus[_, _, _]] // HoldPattern` I am new to `HoldPattern`. Sorry for this.

Comment: `HoldPattern` is wrapped around the pattern which you don't want to evaluate. It may be a good idea for you to read more on the language core / basics. You can search this site for resources, there are plenty of recommendations.

Comment: See the examples in the docs for [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html)